# Graceful handing over resources from initramfs to userspace

Tags: linux, resource-management

There are hardware devices which need userspace suppport, like daemon running and handling parts of interaction not suitable (too complex or policy-related) for kernel space.

Running such daemons is easy once you reach userspace -- you can run'em as a result of hotplug event and don't worry much.

Once initramfs comes to the picture, everything suddenly breaks apart: if the daemon is run from initramfs then it needs to either keep running when execution is switched to regular rootfs, which is particularily hard, given initramfs is freed during switch_root or hand out resources and state to another copy of itself, run from rootfs. Both solutions seem inelegant and hacky.

Is there obvious way to manage such devices and their supporting daemons I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this daemon to mount your real root device ? I guess the answer is yes, otherwise the solution would be to wait for your real root.

I your device is so complicated it needs a daemon to just work, may be you could do part of the job in the kernel, and handle the policy through sysfs attribute ?
I fail to see an example of hardware invlved in mounting the real root deice that would need a daemon to work. Device discovery apply, but you don't need a daemon for the device to actually work. An example would be welcome.

Also, do you really need to switch root ? You could keep your initramfs, and mount whatever you need to have a fully functionnal system under /usr/ That is what I do with some of my embedded system.

Update :
mdev is an embedded alternative to udev, which runsin two mode: on scans sysfs to add device, the other is running for hotplug event. So I guess you don't need to "store" hotplug event, because all the info is still available in sysfs. So the solution is something like :

- run udev from initramfs
- mount real root and switch root
- scan sysfs (does udev do that on startup ?)
- normal operation (ie wait for hotplug event)

Comment: Interesting idea to "just mount", though it's semi-embedded device with package manager, so I'd like to keep uclibc and busybox upgradeable through ipkg which kind of hard if they are kept on initramfs.

Comment: I need a daemon to drive graphical framebuffer, which is needed ASAP to show splash screen (and delaying it for several seconds more is not an option from the marketing POV). In this particular case it is easy to start the daemon, then shut it down and start again on real rootfs, there is little-to-no info shared, but I am interested how to handle it in general case. E.g. how to handle hotplug events so both initramfs can wait for storage to appear and rootfs can receive all events it is interested in, including those happened during initramfs run.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific case? How have the other distributions handled this?

Looking at how Fedora does udev, it starts it up from the initramfs, gets it to do its stuff so the really root fs can be mounted, then shuts it down again before switching.

Comment: My specific case is small daemon that is needed for driving graphical framebuffer (quite specific screen -- one of several eInk controllers). Regarding udev -- interesting. I wonder how do they make sure both udevs get all necessary events, that is, how userspace event get events like "MMC card is here" if this event was delivered to initramfs udev.